# How about a Movie Night?

Tags: discussion, movie-night

I'd like to do another live chat movie night in Mos Eisley. Particularly since I'm home for this entire month so I should be able to attend and I'll do a write up for the blog similar to previous movie nights.

- [Live Chat: The Day the Earth Stood Still 1951](http://thesffblog.com/2015/08/live-chat-the-day-the-earth-stood-still-1951/)
- [Live Chat: Star Trek TOS "Space Seed"](http://thesffblog.com/2013/09/live-chat-star-trek-tos-space-seed/)
- [Live Chat: Star Trek TOS "And the Children Shall Lead"](http://thesffblog.com/2012/08/live-chat-star-trek-tos-and-the-children-shall-lead/)

**I'm hoping for something like Tuesday December 20th, 3:00pm MST (10:00pm GMT)**.

Please suggest a movie (or tv series episode or two?). There is no restriction on a suggestion (save for Science Fiction or Fantasy), but it is nice if you include where the movie might be available for rent, purchase, or legitimate streaming.

Comment: Thanks for taking the initiative with this! Also, glad you included TV series episodes as a possibility. I probably shouldn't post any suggestions for this one since I'm not going to be around on the 20th, but I hope that allowing TV as well as movies continues to be a thing for future movie nights.

Comment: The volume of film nights seems to be declining...

Comment: @Valorum I haven't been able to attend one since The Day the Earth Stood Still.

Comment: @Valorum Praxis has been the 'official' movie night organiser for most of this year, but he's been busy IRL for the last while and - until now - nobody had stepped up to take his place.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I shall be returning to chat in a few months, assuming the CM's don't find another spurious excuse to ban me. Assuming no-one's running them at that point, I'll be happy to start organising them again.

Comment: Thanks for doing this Jack.  I was supposed to do another one after the last one (which was in September) and then hand the "reins" over to Wad...however, some things IRL kept me away from SFF in general.

Comment: Is this voting based on upvotes only, like usual?

Comment: *Movies?* At *night???*

Comment: Soooo..... is this going to happen....

Comment: @skooba yes. Tomorrow

Answer (score 8):

You may think this is trying to be a troll post (you might be right, but then again you might not be)....

## The Star Wars Holiday Special

[image: holiday special poster]

I say this because *everyone* likes to rip on this film, but I counter "How many of you have actually seen it?" I personally have not seen it. This might give an opportunity for others who have not seen it but rag on it anyway a chance to see what all the fuss is actually about!

As far as availability... it is on Youtube!

Comment: It's surely worth it to see it once.  And don't get me wrong, it's quite bad... but it's not as transcendently bad as people often make out.

Comment: Eh, but wasn't that a Thanksgiving movie?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots couldn't tell you....I really have never seen it. I know it is about the Wookie "Life Day" and that is about its :P

Comment: It aired on November 17, 1978. :)

Comment: @KutuluMike Mystery SFF.SE Theater 3K!

Comment: Now that I've seen it, I'm going to have to disagree with @Buzz. "Transcendently bad" is a pretty accurate description.

Answer (score 4):

**DIE HARD**

I would like to nominate one of the greatest Holiday movies of all time, [*Die Hard*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095016/).

> John McClane, officer of the NYPD, tries to save his wife Holly
>   Gennaro and several others that were taken hostage by German terrorist
>   Hans Gruber during a Christmas party at the Nakatomi Plaza in Los
>   Angeles.

[image]

Comment: On topic........?

Comment: Not very Sci fi

Comment: @Valorum Blame Himarm.  He put me up to it ;)

Comment: @JackBNimble Himarm said that it was "spy-fi"...whatever that means :P

Comment: @steelersquirrel - he probably just misspelled something wholly different? :)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile Hahaha!  Good point :)

Comment: The [latest effort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Good_Day_to_Die_Hard) is arguably Spy-fi. This one is a simple action flick

Answer (score 4):

This is a little bit late, but why not the classic piece featured on MST3K, *[Santa Claus Conquers the Martians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus_Conquers_the_Martians)*, starring Pia Zadora and the first appearance of Mrs. Claus in a movie?

[image: Movie Poster]

> The story involves the people of Mars, including Momar ("Mom Martian") and Kimar ("King Martian"). They're worried that their children Girmar ("Girl Martian") and Bomar ("Boy Martian") are watching too much Earth television, most notably station KID-TV's interview with Santa Claus in his workshop at the North Pole. Consulting the ancient 800-year-old Martian sage Chochem (a Yiddish word meaning "genius"), they are advised that the children of Mars are growing distracted due to the society's overly rigid structure; from infancy, all their education is fed into their brains through machines and they are not allowed individuality or freedom of thought.
>
> Chochem notes that he had seen this coming "for centuries", and says the only way to help the children is to allow them their freedom and be allowed to have fun. To do this, they need a Santa Claus figure, like on Earth. Leaving the Chochem's cave, the Martian leaders decide to abduct Santa Claus from Earth and bring him to Mars

Here's the trailer:

It's been released to the Public Doman and the movie is easily found on YouTube (there's two links before a trailer is visible if you type in the name), so it would be easy for people to watch along.

Comment: Mrs Claus? I thought Santa's wife was called **Mary Christmas** (badoom-tish)

Answer (score 3):

### Gremlins

It happens to be relevant to the holiday season, but Gremlins is a nice classic from the 80s.

> A boy inadvertently breaks three important rules concerning his new pet and unleashes a horde of malevolently mischievous monsters on a small town.

**Obligatory 1980s Breakfast Cereal**

Looks like it is available to rent on YouTube, included with Amazon Prime Video in the US, and available for purchase on your standard online markets.